# Creating class for Complex Number in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm leaning oops in python and I'm creating class for complex numbers for doing basic math operations by overriding the operators `+ - * /`. In doing so my updated result (which I'm storing in self) is not getting printed instead it is printing the old value that was passed as argument. Help me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import math

class Complex(object):
    real, imaginary = 0,0
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def __add__(self, no):        
        self.real = self.real + no.real
        self.imaginary = self.imaginary + no.imaginary
        return self

    def __sub__(self, no):
        self.real = self.real - no.real
        self.imaginary = self.imaginary - no.imaginary
        return self

    def __mul__(self, no):
        self.real = self.real * no.real
        self.imaginary = self.imaginary * no.imaginary
        return self

    def __truediv__(self, no):
        self.real = self.real / no.real
        self.imaginary = self.imaginary / no.imaginary
        return self

    def mod(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.real**2 + self.imaginary**2)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary == 0:
            result = "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
        elif self.real == 0:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                result = "0.00+%.2fi" % (self.imaginary)
            else:
                result = "0.00-%.2fi" % (abs(self.imaginary))
        elif self.imaginary > 0:
            result = "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
        else:
            result = "%.2f-%.2fi" % (self.real, abs(self.imaginary))
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = map(float, input().split())
    d = map(float, input().split())
    x = Complex(*c)
    y = Complex(*d)
    print(*map(str, [x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y, x.mod(), y.mod()]), sep='\n')
```

> Input (stdin): 
>  2 1
>  5 6
>  Your Output (stdout)
>   2.00+1.00i
>   2.00+1.00i
>   2.00+1.00i
>   2.00+1.00i
>   2.23606797749979
>   7.810249675906654
>  
>  Expected Output:
>   7.00+7.00i
>   -3.00-5.00i
>   4.00+17.00i
>   0.26-0.11i
>   2.24+0.00i
>   7.81+0.00i

Comment: Are you doing this despite being aware of the built in `complex` class?

Comment: Also, consider having e.g. `__add__` return a new instance, while `__iadd__` operates on `self`. Also, don't forget to return `NotImplemented` for invalid input types you don't care to support.

Comment: Your formulae for `__mul__` and `__truediv__` are simply wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your operator implementations is mutating the attributes of its left operand. So after you execute `x + y`, x becomes the sum of x and y. Then when you execute `x - y`, x becomes the difference of x and y. After `x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y` all finish running, x has returned to its original value, since subtraction cancels out addition and division cancels out multiplication. Then the print function executes and displays your x object four times.

Operator implementations should return a new instance of the class rather than modifying the existing one.

```
import math

class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def __add__(self, no):     
        return Complex(self.real + no.real, self.imaginary + no.imaginary)

    def __sub__(self, no):
        return Complex(self.real - no.real, self.imaginary - no.imaginary)

    def __mul__(self, no):
        return Complex(self.real * no.real, self.imaginary * no.imaginary)

    def __truediv__(self, no):
        return Complex(self.real / no.real, self.imaginary / no.imaginary)

    def mod(self):
        return Complex(math.sqrt(self.real**2 + self.imaginary**2), 0)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary == 0:
            result = "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
        elif self.real == 0:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                result = "0.00+%.2fi" % (self.imaginary)
            else:
                result = "0.00-%.2fi" % (abs(self.imaginary))
        elif self.imaginary > 0:
            result = "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
        else:
            result = "%.2f-%.2fi" % (self.real, abs(self.imaginary))
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Complex(2,1)
    y = Complex(5,6)
    print(*map(str, [x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y, x.mod(), y.mod()]), sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
7.00+7.00i
-3.00-5.00i
10.00+6.00i
0.40+0.17i
2.24+0.00i
7.81+0.00i
```

---

I notice that even with these changes, multiplication and division do not provide the expected result. This is because you can't multiply or divide a complex number just by performing arithmetic on its real and imaginary components separately. `2i * 3i` is not `6i`, for example; it is -6+0i.

Try these implementations:

```
def __mul__(self, no):
    return Complex(self.real * no.real - self.imaginary * no.imaginary, self.real * no.imaginary + no.real * self.imaginary)

def __truediv__(self, no):
    denominator = no.real**2 + no.imaginary**2
    return Complex((self.real*no.real + self.imaginary*no.imaginary) / denominator, (self.imaginary*no.real - self.real*no.imaginary) / denominator)
```

Now the output for multiplication and division will be `4.00+17.00i` and
`0.26-0.11i`.

Comment: Note that the results for `__mul__` and `__truediv__` don't match their expected values (because they are mathematically incorrect).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, good observation. I will provide cromulent alternatives in a moment.

Comment: Is there ever a case where `"%.2f%+.2fi" % (self.real, self.imag)` wouldn't work? Zen of python #whatever: there are no special cases.

Comment: Also, you can just `print(x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y, x.mod(), y.mod(), sep='\n')`. The whole point of `print` is that it stringifies all inputs.

Comment: @Kevin: "cromulent"?

Comment: @martineau, cromulent: (adj) - acceptable or adequate. There is some dispute about whether "cromulent" is itself cromulent, but I think it is :-)

Comment: @Kevin: Hmm, learn something everyday—it wasn't in the [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=cromulent) I initially looked in, nor my local American Heritage Dictionary.